# convert C or C++ constant to Java

Tags: java, c++, c

I have the following C or C++ constant:

```
static const char *selstr2 = "oooo"
                             "oC o"
                             "o  o"
                             "oooo";
```

Right now I don't understand what is analog to this in Java. Is it a Java String or String[]?

Comment: try `public static final String CONST = "oooooC  oo  ooooo";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing, note that in this context, your C-style string is equivalent, upon unobfuscating the multiline presentation and the concatenating behaviour of successive `""` in this context, to

```
static const char *selstr2 = "oooooC oo  ooooo";
```

`selstr2` is a pointer to a `char[17]` literal in C and a `const char[17]` literal in C++ that's *decayed* to a `const char*` pointer type. Note the important divergence of C and C++ here: although the type is not `const` in C, you still cannot modify the contents.

You might be tempted to think that this is equivalent to a `java.lang.String`. But it isn't on two important points: (1) Java strings are *wider*; they consist of Java `char` types, which are 16 bit unsigned types. And (2) The NUL-terminator is not specified, implicit, or perhaps even present.

I'd say therefore that a `java.lang.String` is closer to a C++ `std::basic_string<std::uint16_t>` with UTF-16 *encoding*, and the C-style string in many ways is closest to an array of bytes in Java, with an extra 0 at the end.

This all said, you'll probably find that

```
static final java.lang.String selstr2 = "oooooC oo  ooooo";
```

will be fit for purpose, unless you intend to interoperate between the two languages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need some time in order to finish porting the code to Java in order to validate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to a `String`. (As close as a C string ever gets to that anyway.)

In C and C++, string literals that are only separated by whitespace are treated as a single long literal.